# Figure numbers does not match with the list of figures in classicthesis

Tags: captions, classicthesis

I am using `classicthesis` version `2012/08/12 v4.1`. I would like to have the figure numbers to include the chapter number (such as 1.1, 1.1, ..., 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, ...) and have the figure counter reset for each chapter. The following is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[
                %twoside, 
                openright,
                titlepage, numbers=noenddot, headinclude,%1headlines,
                footinclude=true, cleardoublepage=empty,
                BCOR=30mm, paper=letter, fontsize=11pt, % Binding correction, paper type and font size
                dottedtoc,
                ngerman, american, % Languages
                ]{scrreprt} 

\PassOptionsToPackage{%
                    eulerchapternumbers,
                    listings,
                    %drafting,
                    pdfspacing,
                    %floatperchapter,
                    %linedheaders,%
                    subfig,
                    beramono,
                    % eulermath, % This changes the font for math equations.
                    parts}{classicthesis}

\usepackage{tabularx} % Better tables
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt} % Increase table row height
\newcommand{\tableheadline}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myfloatalign}{\centering} % To be used with each float for alignment
\usepackage{caption} 
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{myformat}{#1~\thechapter.#2}
\captionsetup{format=hang, font=small, labelformat=myformat} 

\usepackage[position=t,singlelinecheck=off,font={it}]{subfig}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{ch01}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
    \caption{This is the figure in chapter number one.}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\chapter{ch02}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
    \caption{This is the figure in chapter number two.}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I was able to modify the figure captioning using `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{myformat}{#1~\thechapter.#2}` and it works fine inside each chapter. However, when I look at the list of figures, it is not compatible with the figure number inside each chapter, i.e., it does not have the chapter number. Could someone help me with that?

Also is there an easier way for resetting the counter to zero before each chapter? should I reset the counter every time before each chapter? Can we have something in the preamble that does automatically reset the counter to zero when it detects a new chapter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change you made only affects the label in captions. What you want can be achieved using

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[
                %twoside, 
                openright,
                titlepage, numbers=noenddot, headinclude,%1headlines,
                footinclude=true, cleardoublepage=empty,
                BCOR=30mm, paper=letter, fontsize=11pt, % Binding correction, paper type and font size
                dottedtoc,
                ngerman, american, % Languages
                ]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[%
                    eulerchapternumbers,
                    listings,
                    %drafting,
                    pdfspacing,
                    %floatperchapter,
                    %linedheaders,%
                    subfig,
                    beramono,
                    % eulermath, % This changes the font for math equations.
                    parts]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[position=t,singlelinecheck=off,font={it}]{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx} % Better tables
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{caption} 

\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt} % Increase table row height
\newcommand{\tableheadline}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myfloatalign}{\centering} % To be used with each float for alignment
\captionsetup{format=hang, font=small} 

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{ch01}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
    \caption{This is the figure in chapter number one.}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\chapter{ch02}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
    \caption{This is the figure in chapter number two.}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting LoF:

[image]

Without additional packages, you could achieve the same using

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
\@addtoreset{figure}{chapter}
\makeatother
```